# How to draw sine wave curve using sin() function and canvas in android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, trigonometry

I am new to android and I am trying to draw a sine wave on the screen on the trigger of accelerometer  values change. I just need a plain sine wave dynamically drawn on the screen(confined to screen). I can draw the coordinates on Canvas and validate screen dimensions but I am not able to think of how to convert sine values(ranging from 0 to 1) to the screen coordinates.

I was trying something like this in onSensorChanged():

```
tvarY = sin(tvarX)*2.0;  // tvarX and tvarY are double values
tvarX= (tvarX+ 2);        // 2.0 is for magnifying

xPosition = (float)tvarX;
yPosition = (float)tvarY;
```

But the values of tvarx using this approach are always switching between back and forth from infinity to 0. Can anybody please suggest me any approach to change the values and convert them into screen coordinates for drawing a proper sine wave?

Thanks :-)

Comment: '/ 2.0 is for magnifying' No. That will only shift the wave to the right. But you already used X to calculate Y so it makes no sense to change the X afterwards. Or is 2.0 your deltaX for the next X? 'values of tvarx using this approach are always switching between back and forth from infinity to 0. '. You are the one who determines the range of X. After that you calculate the Y with Y= sin(X);.

Comment: Please show the whole loop where you draw the sinus. Complete with initialisations.

Comment: I should be changing x linearly to draw a sine wave, my bad. But how should I use the delta on the values to magnify them to screen size?

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use function:
`path.rQuadTo(float dx1, float dy1, float dx2, float dy2)`

Same as `quadTo`, but the coordinates are considered relative to the last point on this contour.

I wrote a sentence for your reference:

```
Path mpath = new Path();
mpath.moveTo(0, 100);
mpath.rQuadTo(20, 5, 40, 0);
mpath.rQuadTo(20, -5, 40, 0);
```

You can try once, then you will get a sine wave like this picture:

[image: sine wave]

I think this method will be easier comparing with converting value of sin to coordinate.

Answer (score 6):

Create custom view:

```html
import android.animation.ValueAnimator
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View

class WaveView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var amplitude = 30f.toDp() // scale
    private var speed = 0f
    private val path = Path()
    private var paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private var animator: ValueAnimator? = null

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        animator?.cancel()
        animator = createAnimator().apply { start() }
    }

    override fun onDraw(c: Canvas) = c.drawPath(path, paint)

    private fun createAnimator(): ValueAnimator {
        return ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, Float.MAX_VALUE).apply {
            repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
            addUpdateListener {
                speed -= WAVE_SPEED
                createPath()
                invalidate()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createPath() {
        path.reset()
        paint.color = Color.parseColor("#1da6f9")
        path.moveTo(0f, height.toFloat())
        path.lineTo(0f, amplitude)
        var i = 0
        while (i < width + 10) {
            val wx = i.toFloat()
            val wy = amplitude * 2 + amplitude * Math.sin((i + 10) * Math.PI / WAVE_AMOUNT_ON_SCREEN + speed).toFloat()
            path.lineTo(wx, wy)
            i += 10
        }
        path.lineTo(width.toFloat(), height.toFloat())
        path.close()
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        animator?.cancel()
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
    }

    companion object {
        const val WAVE_SPEED = 0.3f
        const val WAVE_AMOUNT_ON_SCREEN = 350
    }

    private fun Float.toDp() = this * context.resources.displayMetrics.density
}
```

In activity layout(ConstraintLayout):

```
<com.uvn.test.WaveView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```